# PHP - scraping google groups page

Tags: php, web-scraping, google-groups

I am new to PHP, and i'm trying to get myself some data from a google groups page. 
My goal is to get only the time, when was latest post released, but for testing here i'm trying at least get some data (posts). But when i launch my program, i won't get anything useful (just header file and  saying i need to enable javascript, then reload the page, but i don't know how to deal with this)

`$input_group = file_get_html('https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.php');
 echo $input_group;`

Then, if this will somehow work, i plan to use something like this for getting teh data. Maybye not the best solution tho. This worked for other pages, but for some reason not here.

```
foreach($input_group->find("someTagHere") as $a){
    echo $a->plaintext;
}
```

Thanks.